# If P = NP then EXP^P = NEXP^NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, polynomial-time, nondeterminism, p-vs-np

I believe that if **P = NP**, then that would imply **EXP = NEXP** (because of the padding argument), and then **EXP^P = NEXP^NP** (we could replace **EXP** with **NEXP** since they are equal, and replace **P** with **NP**, since they are equal).

Is there any error in this affirmation? I am not sure if there is anything that I am not considering and that would prevent the last step from being correct, for example.

Comment: Relativization is not as easy as it seems. See [that post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/76021) for some explainations. Also I know that $\mathsf{EXP}^{\mathsf{P}} = \mathsf{EXP}$, but it is not so sure, even with the condition $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$, that $\mathsf{NEXP}^{\mathsf{NP}} = \mathsf{NEXP}$. (Sorry I don't know the answer to that question).

Comment: Your edit history is available on the system. There is no reason to add editorial remarks to your post.

Comment: If you're not sure about the veracity of the claim, try proving it from first principles.